# "fortune" command no output when running as daemon

Tags: command-line, bash

I execute the `fortune` command from a daemon, but I don't get any output. If I run the bash-file from command-line I get the output without problems.

```
echo "$(fortune)"
```

The daemon is the [Telegram-CLI](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) with `-d` parameter.

Why? and is there a workaround?

Comment: Why `echo "$(fortune)"` and not simply `fortune`?

Comment: Wait a minute. Daemon processes are not connected to a terminal, and have no stdout. Where do you expect the fortune to be displayed?

Comment: @glennjackman It should be send in a message through Telegram-cli to the user who requested it. To get the result, I use `var="$(cmds.sh fortune)" to get the result.